# What is the difference between using @Qualifier annotation and directly injecting bean in spring?

Tags: java, spring

Suppose I have a program

```
@Component
public interface Coach{
  public String giveCoaching();
}

@Component
public TennisCoach implements Coach{
  @Override
  public String giveCoaching(){
    return "Teaching forhand";
  }
}
```

I have two Demo classes in which I have injected the bean in different ways. what is the difference in both the injections

```
public class AppDemo{
  @AutoWired
  @Qualifier("tennisCoach")
  private Coach theCoach;
}

public class AppDemo{
  @AutoWired
  private TennisCoach tennisCoach;
  }
}
```

Comment: The field names are different. You may not want the field name to be the same as the bean implementation name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have more than 1 implementation for you interface, you will get an exception when Autowiring the bean. At that time `@Qualifier` will be used to choose the  required implementation

```
@Component
public interface Coach{
  public String giveCoaching();
}

@Component
public TennisCoach implements Coach{
  @Override
  public String giveCoaching(){
    return "Teaching forhand";
  }
}

@Component
public CricketCoach implements Coach{
  @Override
  public String giveCoaching(){
    return "Teaching forbat";
  }
}
```

Now the ambiguity will occur when you autowire the `Coach` Interface like below

```
public class AppDemo{
  @AutoWired      
  private Coach theCoach;
}
```

So you have to qualify the right bean for the `Coach`Interface like below.

```
public class AppDemo{
  @AutoWired
  @Qualifier("tennisCoach")      
  private Coach theCoach;
}
```

Alternatively you can use `@Primary` annotation on top of any one of the implementation so that the Spring Container will by default choose the bean in case of more than 1 implementation for an interface.

But in the code below, you are directly creating the object for the implementation rather than interface.

```
public class AppDemo{
  @AutoWired
  private TennisCoach tennisCoach;
  }
}
```

Comment: Will both the implementation have the same behaviour?

Comment: yes, using Primary or Qualifier annotation will have the same behavior with auto wiring

Answer (score 0):

`@Qualifier` annotation is used when your interface has more than one implementing class, You should opt for the one you want inject as a bean in spring context.

Comment: Suppose I have multiple implementation of the Coach class. In one implementation i will inject using @Qualifier and in other i will directly inject the bean. My question is: "Is there any difference?"